# Jquery ajax invalid assignment left-hand side [Break On This Error] data: 'StudentClass'=StudentClass,

Tags: jquery

```
$("#class").change(function(){
        var StudentClass = $(this).val();
        //alert(StudentClass);
        $.ajax({
          url: "getStudentClass.php",
          type: "post",
          data: 'StudentClass'=StudentClass,
          success: function(data){
              alert(data);
          },
          error:function(){
              alert("failure");
              $("#result").html('there is error while submit');
          }   
       }); 

    });
```

the apove code give me this Error invalid assignment left-hand side

```
[Break On This Error]   

data: 'StudentClass'=StudentClass,

midterm_test.php (line 28, col 24)
```

any one with an idea y this is happening

Answer (score 1):

You're assigning a value to a string, which isn't really valid. You probably want to pass an object instead:

```
data: {
    'StudentClass': StudentClass
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Oh wow, I can't believe I made the same typo and found this.  You can assign string to data, I always have.

```
data: 'StudentClass'=StudentClass,
```

Should be

```
data: 'StudentClass='+StudentClass,
```